# Android Emulator: device is pending authentication please accept debugging session on device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Trying to debug an Android app on the emulator running Android 14 (api34) from Android Studio but I'm getting the error:

"device is pending authentication please accept debugging session on device."

In the device emulator window.